# Custom FragmentDialog with round corners and not 100% screen width

Tags: android, custom-component, android-dialogfragment

I am creating a custom fragment dialog with round corners and with layout that would not fill the screen width (I would prefer if it just wrapped its content).

this is my `rounded_dialog.xml` in drawable folder, which is called by my Custom `ThemeWithCorners` as a background for the dialog. I also tried to set it as background to the linear layout which creates its content but nothing works.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" 
>
<solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
<corners android:radius="20dp"
/>
</shape>
```

and this is how i call the dialog:

```
final String FTAG = "TAG_FRAGMENT_DIALOG_CALENDAR";
    dialog = (CalendarDialog) fm.findFragmentByTag(FTAG);
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (dialog != null)
    {
        ft.remove(dialog);
    }
    dialog = CalendarDialog.newInstance(this);      
    dialog.setCancelable(true);

    ft.add(dialog, FTAG);
    ft.show(dialog);
    ft.commit();
```

In onCreate method of the dialog I set the style and theme:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.ThemeWithCorners);      
}
```

This is the onCreateView method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
v = (MyCalendar)inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_dialog, container, true)
    return v;
}
```

I also tried to add this to onCreateDialog method as other answers on SO suggested but did not work either:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    Dialog d =  super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutParams lp=d.getWindow().getAttributes();
    d.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
    lp.width=-2;lp.height=-2;lp.gravity=Gravity.CENTER;
    lp.dimAmount=0;            
    lp.flags=LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;

    return d;
}
```

So to sum it up, I want round corners, not 100% width of the screen, it preferably should wrap its content. Please, please, I need some help, I am really desperate about this, I´v ebeen trying it for days!

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Well, I just found a solution, I am not really happy with it though.

I set the background (rounded_dialog.xml) for the dialog like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<corners android:radius="10dp" />
<padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then I set this to my dialog in its ´onCreateView´ method this way below. The rounded corners are not really necessary in this piece of code as the background is transparent, but the padding is important, because the dialog is still in fact as wide as the screen, but the padding makes it look like it is not.

```
getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.rounded_dialog);
```

And in the end I set background of the dialog´s components to another custom drawable which makes the corners round. I have a LinearLayout with RelativeLayout at the top and TextView at the bottom, so I set @null to the parent LinearLayout and set two different custom drawables to the two parts, one of which has rounded bottomCorners and the other one topCorners.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/title_round"  
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/blue_title_round_top"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    >
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/calendarHint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I believe there is a more proper solution to this as this is correct just visually, not really functionally, but enough correct for this case.

Answer (score 146):

**Dialog background:** `dialog_rounded_bg.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

**Dialog layout:** `dialog_rounded.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dialog_rounded_bg"
    android:minWidth="260dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="24dp">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

**Dialog fragment:** `RoundedDialog.java`

```
public class RoundedDialog extends DialogFragment {
    ...
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_rounded, container, false);
        // Set transparent background and no title
        if (getDialog() != null && getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        }
        return view;
    }
    ...
}
```

[image: Rounded dialog]

**Update:** If you don't set the flag `Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE`, a [blue line appears](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37738690/6305235) on top of the dialog in devices with Android ≤ 4.4.

Comment: What font have you used in the dialog?

Comment: It's a custom font (Maison Neue).

Comment: This solution also worked with `ConstraintLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 9):

Updated 2022 answer with Kotlin and View Binding -

```
class InternetLostDialog : DialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: DialogInternetLostBinding

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        binding = DialogInternetLostBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context))
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity())
        isCancelable = false
        builder.setView(binding.root)
        binding.root.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().finish()
        }
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        return dialog
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Another way:**

Use `setStyle()` in `onCreate()` method to **apply a style** to your `DialogFragment`.
Then, you can use `android:background` same as always in the **root view** of `your_layout.xml` file.

---

Steps:

1. **style.xml** file (in **res** folder) :

```
<style name="DialogTheme_transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!--You can set other style items also, such as animations and etc-->
</style>
```

2. Create `your_layout.xml` file in the **layout folder**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_corner_dialog">
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

3. Create `bg_corner_dialog.xml` file in the **drawable folder**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    android:dither="true">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

4. Finally apply `style` and `layout` to the your `DialogFragment`:

```
public class CustomDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogTheme_transparent);
        ...
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, v);
        //init UI Elements...
        return v;
    }

}
```

I hope this helps you.
Best wishes

Answer (score 3):

There is a quick fix for DialogFragment. For example, in the method onCreateDialog() **add style** in AlertDialog.Builder(context, style):

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog_lauout, null);
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.custom_alert_dialog)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
                    // do something
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .create();
}
```

**In styles folder** `custom_alert_dialog`

```
<style name="custom_alert_dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/corner_background</item>
</style>
```

In drawable folder `corner_background.xml`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />
```

[image]

It's tested for API >= 21

Answer (score 2):

An updated solution that works for me using Kotlin.

I set the background (rounded_dialog.xml) for the dialog like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="28dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
</shape>
```

then calculating the screen width programmatically then subtract the Margin value from it, using this code snippet.

```
val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        requireActivity().windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
```

then inside onStart callback I applied that width minus Margin.
here is the full code.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class CancelDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        if (dialog != null && dialog?.window != null) {
            dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            dialog?.window?.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        }
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cancel_dialog, container, false)
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        requireActivity().windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)

        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        dialog?.window?.setLayout(width-64, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
    }


}
```

XML Layout `fragment_cancel_dialog`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="32dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_dialog"
    tools:context=".ui.orders.CancelDialogFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Reason of cancellation"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/firstNameTIL"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstNameTIL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:hintAnimationEnabled="false"
        app:hintEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView9">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/firstNameET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_text_bg"
            android:drawablePadding="12dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:paddingHorizontal="16dp"
            android:paddingVertical="16dp"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:textColorHint="@color/black" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
        android:paddingHorizontal="56dp"
        android:text="@string/confirmStr"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/firstNameTIL" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For Any One who wants to Use the AlertDialogBuilder and transparent the background and set the Drawable in XML file.

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">

<item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

Set this Theme on Builder like below

```
private val builder: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context,R.style.DialogStyle)
    .setView(dialogView)
```

where R.drawable.dialog_background is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/dialog_bg_color"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to make rounded corners, its much easier if u make cardview as the root of your layout and add below code in onCreateView():
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transpare‌​nt)

Comment: it doesnt work for me, has no effect on dialog displayed

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and it misses the simplest way of achieving rounded edges in a DialogFragment component. You can achieve this with one liner:

```
override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog
```