# How to make custom dialog with rounded corners in android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-dialog

**What I am trying to do:** I am trying to make a custom dialog in android With rounded corners.

**What is happening:** I am able to make custom dialog but it doesn't have rounded corners. I tried adding a selector but still I couldn't achieve rounded corners.

Below is my code for the same:

---

**Java code:**

```
private void launchDismissDlg() {

        dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dlg_dismiss);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

        Button btnReopenId = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnReopenId);
        Button btnCancelId = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelId);

        btnReopenId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });


        btnCancelId.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



            }
        });
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.show();

    }
```

**xml code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="&quot;I WOULD LIKE TO DISMISS THE VENDOR&quot;"
                android:textColor="@color/col_dlg_blue_light"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="BECAUSE"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>



        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnReopenId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/col_dlg_green_light"
                android:text="REOPEN"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelId"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/col_dlg_pink_light"
                android:text="CANCEL"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you talking about floating menu?

Comment: @Apurva ... i have not used floating menu ... but i am talking about an alert dialog(custom)

Comment: I was asking about floating menu because I've seen round cornered pop up in only that. Never seen dialog with rounded corners.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501488/android-alertdialog-with-rounded-corners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501488/android-alertdialog-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 518, accepted):

Create an XML file in drawable, say `dialog_bg.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="30dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

set it as the background in your layout XML:

```
android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
```

Set the background of the dialog's root view to transparent, because Android puts your dialog layout within a root view that hides the corners in your custom layout.

*Java:*

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

*Kotlin:*

```
dialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the button's background will also be transparent.

Comment: `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` is what mising on most of the other SO threads!
+1

Comment: Background TRANSPARENT is not showing please help me sir,,,@koma yip

Comment: Yes sir,i have recylierview on top i need TRANSPARENT dialog.but it is showing white color dialog,not showing background transparent...@KomaYip

Comment: I used this and lower corners are rounded now. but upper corners are still not rounded.

Comment: @VivekPratapSingh, i think the upper part not being fully shown?

Comment: `setBackgroundDrawable` seems to be deprecated... any alternatives to that?

Comment: Add `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));` before `setContentView`

Comment: This works except that the part where the dialog's buttons are shown are transparent :/

Comment: instead @color/white and save the white color in colors.xml, you can use @android:color/white

Comment: Where do I have to place dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT)); ? setBackgroundDrawable doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Daniëlle dialog is the instance of your Dialog object you wish to make rounded, just change it to your own variable

Comment: Superior answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719997/337455

Comment: Another issue is that if there is a list in the dialog, the ripple effect from the click won't conform to the rounded corners

Answer (score 62):

With the Androidx library and Material Components Theme you can override the **`getTheme()`** method:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment

class RoundedDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog

    //....

}
```

with:

```
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">16dp</item>
</style>
```

Or you can use the **`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`** included in the Material Components Library:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder

class RoundedAlertDialog : DialogFragment() {

    //...

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        return MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(requireActivity(), R.style.MaterialAlertDialog_rounded)
                .setTitle("Test")
                .setMessage("Message")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .create()
    }

}
```

with:

```
<style name="MaterialAlertDialog_rounded" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/DialogCorners</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogCorners">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">16dp</item>
</style>
```

[image]

If you don't need a `DialogFragment` just use the **`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`**.

Comment: Will _probably_ only work from API level 28 upwards...

Comment: @arkascha why should it work only for API 28+?

Comment: Sorry, I have to correct my comment: _the first approch_ will only work from API level 28 upwards, since `dialogCornerRadius` has not been implemented before. Actually AndroidStudio points out that issue.

Comment: Still work very well on API 32.

Comment: Works for min sdk 27

Comment: Making a subclass for a detail like rounded corners might result in Alan Kay personally showing up at your door to have a chat.

Answer (score 36):

You need to do the following:

- Create a background with rounded corners for the Dialog's background:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle" >

      <solid android:color="#fff" />

      <corners
          android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
          android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
          android:topRightRadius="8dp" />

  </shape>
  ```
- Now in your Dialog's XML file in the root layout use that background with required margin:

  ```
  android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
  android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
  android:background="@drawable/dialog_background"
  ```
- finally in the java part you need to do this:

  ```
  dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
  dialog.setContentView(layoutResId);
  View v = getWindow().getDecorView();
  v.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.transparent);
  ```

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: if you want to use same value for all corners then you should use `<corners android:radius="8dp"/>` , otherwise you'll get rendering issues

Comment: @Mehran good point. Thanks for pointing that out. Can you also share the source of this info?

Comment: @SMR `Path.isConvex is not supported` this is the warning you usually get in your layout if you use a shape with same value for all corners. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34736981/6605907

Answer (score 31):

`dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

this works for me

Answer (score 24):

Setting

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

will prevent dialog to cast a shadow.

Solution is to use

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.dialog_rounded_background);
```

where is R.drawable.dialog_rounded_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
            <solid
                android:color="@color/dialog_bg_color"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="30dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: Most elegant and simple solution that worked on API 27, Android 8.1 Oreo.

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2020 if you're still stuck with Theme.AppCompat

Answer (score 17):

If you use **Material Components**:

CustomDialog.kt

```
class CustomDialog: DialogFragment() {

    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog

}
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">dimen</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It was the solution for me, thanks! In my case, I added text and background color: 
<style name="RoundedCornersDialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog">
        <item name="dialogCornerRadius">15dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

Answer (score 15):

dimen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <integer name="weight">1</integer>

    <dimen name="dialog_top_radius">21dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="textview_dialog_head_min_height">50dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="textview_dialog_drawable_padding">5dp</dimen>

    <dimen name="button_dialog_layout_margin">3dp</dimen>


</resources>
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="TextView.Dialog">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">@dimen/dimen_size</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">@dimen/dimen_size</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView.Dialog.Head">
        <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/textview_dialog_head_min_height</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_title_style</item>
        <item name="android:drawablePadding">@dimen/textview_dialog_drawable_padding</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextView.Dialog.Text">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Font.Medium.16</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/button_min_height</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/Font.Medium.20</item>
    </style>

 <style name="Button.Dialog">
        <item name="android:layout_weight">@integer/weight</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/button_dialog_layout_margin</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Button.Dialog.Middle">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_primary_selector</item>
    </style>
```

dialog_title_style.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="@color/primaryDark"
        android:startColor="@color/primaryDark" />

    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dialog_top_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dialog_top_radius" />

</shape>
```

dialog_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/backgroundDialog" />
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/dialog_top_radius"
        android:topRightRadius="@dimen/dialog_top_radius" />
    <padding />
</shape>
```

dialog_one_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/dailog_background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialogOneButtonTitle"
        style="@style/TextView.Dialog.Head"
        android:text="Process Completed" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialogOneButtonText"
            style="@style/TextView.Dialog.Text"
            android:text="Return the main menu" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/dialogOneButtonOkButton"
                style="@style/Button.Dialog.Middle"
                android:text="Ok" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

OneButtonDialog.java

```
package com.example.sametoztoprak.concept.dialogs;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.sametoztoprak.concept.R;
import com.example.sametoztoprak.concept.models.DialogFields;

/**
 * Created by sametoztoprak on 26/09/2017.
 */

public class OneButtonDialog extends Dialog implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static OneButtonDialog oneButtonDialog;
    private static DialogFields dialogFields;

    private Button dialogOneButtonOkButton;
    private TextView dialogOneButtonText;
    private TextView dialogOneButtonTitle;

    public OneButtonDialog(AppCompatActivity activity) {
        super(activity);
    }

    public static OneButtonDialog getInstance(AppCompatActivity activity, DialogFields dialogFields) {
        OneButtonDialog.dialogFields = dialogFields;
        return oneButtonDialog = (oneButtonDialog == null) ? new OneButtonDialog(activity) : oneButtonDialog;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_one_button);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        dialogOneButtonTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogOneButtonTitle);
        dialogOneButtonText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dialogOneButtonText);
        dialogOneButtonOkButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogOneButtonOkButton);

        dialogOneButtonOkButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        dialogOneButtonTitle.setText(dialogFields.getTitle());
        dialogOneButtonText.setText(dialogFields.getText());
        dialogOneButtonOkButton.setText(dialogFields.getOneButton());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.dialogOneButtonOkButton:

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Excuse me, where is DialogFields (imported in java)? Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I made a new way without having a background drawable is that make it have **CardView as parent** and give it a `app:cardCornerRadius="20dp"` and then add this in the java class `dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

It's another way to make it .

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder to create custom dialog with rounded corners.

First create a style for the material dialog like this :

```
<style name="MyRounded.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CustomDialog.Rounded
    </item>
    <item name="colorSurface">@color/YOUR_COLOR</item>
</style>

<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CustomDialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">10dp</item>
</style>
```

then create a Alert Dialog object in Java class like this :

```
AlertDialog alertDialog =  new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this,R.style.MyRounded_MaterialComponents_MaterialAlertDialog)  // for fragment you can use getActivity() instead of this 
                    .setView(R.layout.custom_layout) // custom layout is here 
                    .show();

            final EditText editText = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_layout_text);   // access to text view of custom layout         
            Button btn = alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.custom_layout_btn);

            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d(TAG, "onClick: " + editText.getText().toString());
                }
            });
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: the most correct way, do not forget to use MaterialAlertDialogBuilder instead of AlertDialog.Builder

Answer (score 8):

For anyone who like do things in XML, specially in case where you are using Navigation architecture component actions in order to navigate to dialogs

You can use:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dialog.Alert">

    <!-- dialog_background is drawable shape with corner radius -->
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/dialog_background</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is a Basic Solution:

```
 <style name="Style_Dialog_Rounded_Corner" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_rounded_corner</item>
        <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">85%</item>
    </style>
```

in Drawable create shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="12dp" />
</shape>
```

Pass style in Builder Constructor

```
AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this,R.style.Style_Dialog_Rounded_Corner).create();
```

Comment: Other solutions use both "android:background" and "android:windowBackground", but the later is enough to achieve the same result, as it is proposed in this solution. Attribute "android:windowMinWidthMinor" is not mandatory, as it is inherited from the parent.

Comment: In this solution the dialog buttons also become invisible (I think white).

Comment: `windowMinWidthMinor` is the key to glory! Without this I was facing some UI issues in DatePickerDialog

Answer (score 7):

You can use the shape for the background as-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Have a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15421271/custom-fragmentdialog-with-round-corners-and-not-100-screen-width) for the details.

Answer (score 7):

simplest way is to use from

> CardView and its card:cardCornerRadius

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/cardlist_item"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="130dp"
 card:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
 android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
 android:background="@color/white">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12sp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

> And when you are creating your Dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: this solution doesn't allow CardView elevation shadow to be fully displayed

Answer (score 5):

For API level >= 28 available attribute `android:dialogCornerRadius` . To support previous API versions need use

```xml
<style name="RoundedDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_bg</item>
    </style>
```

where dialog_bg.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="16dp"
        android:right="16dp">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners
                android:radius="8dp" />

            <padding
                android:left="16dp"
                android:right="16dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: For what is the layer list / the transparent shape?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the complete solution if you want to control the **corner radius** of the dialog and preserve **elevation shadow**

Dialog:

```
class OptionsDialog: DialogFragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_options, container)
}

}
```

dialog_options.xml layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="40dp"
    app:cardElevation="20dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="12dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        id="@+id/actual_content_goes_here"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

The key is to wrap the CardView with another ViewGroup (here FrameLayout) and set margins to create space for the elevation shadow.

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin, I am using a class **DoubleButtonDialog.Java** with line  `window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))` as important one

```
class DoubleButtonDialog(context: Context) : Dialog(context, R.style.DialogTheme) {

    private var cancelableDialog: Boolean = true
    private var titleDialog: String? = null
    private var messageDialog: String? = null
    private var leftButtonDialog: String = "Yes"
    //    private var rightButtonDialog: String? = null
    private var onClickListenerDialog: OnClickListener? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
        //requestWindowFeature(android.view.Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        setCancelable(cancelableDialog)
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_double_button)
//        val btnNegative = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNegative)
//        btnNegative.visibility = View.GONE
//        if (rightButtonDialog != null) {
//            btnNegative.visibility = View.VISIBLE
//            btnNegative.text = rightButtonDialog
//            btnNegative.setOnClickListener {
//                dismiss()
//                onClickListenerDialog?.onClickCancel()
//            }
//        }
        val btnPositive = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnPositive)
        btnPositive.text = leftButtonDialog
        btnPositive.setOnClickListener {
            onClickListenerDialog?.onClick()
            dismiss()
        }
        (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.title)).text = titleDialog
        (findViewById<TextView>(R.id.message)).text = messageDialog
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    constructor(
        context: Context, cancelableDialog: Boolean, titleDialog: String?,
        messageDialog: String, leftButtonDialog: String, /*rightButtonDialog: String?,*/
        onClickListenerDialog: OnClickListener
    ) : this(context) {
        this.cancelableDialog = cancelableDialog
        this.titleDialog = titleDialog
        this.messageDialog = messageDialog
        this.leftButtonDialog = leftButtonDialog
//        this.rightButtonDialog = rightButtonDialog
        this.onClickListenerDialog = onClickListenerDialog
    }
}


interface OnClickListener {
    //    fun onClickCancel()
    fun onClick()
}
```

In layout, we can create a dialog_double_button.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_double_button"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10"
            android:fontFamily="@font/campton_semi_bold"
            android:textColor="@color/red_dark4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_24"
            tools:text="@string/dial" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            style="@style/TextViewStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/semi_gray_2"
            tools:text="@string/diling_police_number" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_10"
            android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="@dimen/dimen_5">

        <!--<Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNegative"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_40"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10"
            android:layout_weight=".4"
            android:text="@string/cancel" />-->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPositive"
            style="@style/ButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/red_dark4"
            android:fontFamily="@font/campton_semi_bold"
            android:padding="@dimen/dimen_10"
            android:text="@string/proceed"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_20" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

then use **drawable.xml** as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="@dimen/dimen_10" />
    <padding
        android:left="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:top="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:right="@dimen/dimen_10"
        android:bottom="@dimen/dimen_10" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a xml in drawable ,say customd.xml.

then set it at background in your custom Dialog layout xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/customd"
```

finally in the java part for custom Dialog class you need to do this:

```
public class Customdialoque extends DialogFragment {

public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customdialoque, container, false);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way in kotlin:

```
val model = ShapeAppearanceModel()
                .toBuilder()
                .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, 32.0f)
                .build()
val shape = MaterialShapeDrawable(model)
shape.fillColor = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(context, R.color.white)          
ViewCompat.setBackground(dialogContentView, shape)
```

And then change the dialog window

```
dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make alert dialog (or dialog) with round corners and NOT TRANSPARENT buttons I did next:

In `activity/fragment`:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getContext(),R.style.alert_dialog_round_corners);
View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT_OF_DIALOG_CONTENTS,null);
AlertDialog dialog =
            builder.setView(dialogView)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // your code for OK button action
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // your code for Cancel button action
                }
            })
            .create();

    dialog.show();
```

Then, add required style to `themes.xml`:

```
<!-- this is for your dialog. To make round corners -->
<style name="alert_dialog_round_corners" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/alert_dialog_button_style</item>
</style>

<!-- this one is for your buttons. To make them NOT TRANSPARENT -->
<style name="alert_dialog_button_style" parent="">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/alert_dialog_button_background</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

Then you should create drawables for dialog and buttons (`dialog_background`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <corners
        android:radius="15dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

And in `alert_dialog_button_background` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="#F4F4F4" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented rounded dialog using **CardView** in the custom layout and setting its corner radius.

Here's my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/bottomSheet"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/padding_5dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/main_gradient_bg"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subdomain_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans"
        android:text="@string/enter_subdomain"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_45dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/subdomain_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_info_24" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subdomain_edit_text_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dimen_20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subdomain_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/proceed_btn"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_150dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/primary_btn_bg"
        android:text="@string/proceed"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/size_18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/subdomain_edit_text_bottom_sheet" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

After that, i called it in **Kotlin** as follows :-

```
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
    val viewGroup: ViewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content)
    val dialogView: View = 
    LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.subdomain_bottom_sheet, 
    viewGroup, false)
    val alertDialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
    alertDialog.setView(dialogView,0,0,0,0)
    alertDialog.show()
    val windowParam = WindowManager.LayoutParams()
    windowParam.copyFrom(alertDialog.window!!.attributes)
    windowParam.width = AppConstant.getDisplayMetricsWidth(mContext) - 100
    windowParam.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    windowParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    alertDialog.window!!.attributes = windowParam
    
   
    alertDialog.window!!.setBackgroundDrawable
    (ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

Where **last line** is very important. Missing that would cause a color(mostly white) to show behind the corners.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did round the corners for me, but unless I switched to a Material design theme, making the window background transparent had no effect and I still saw a square, shadowed background of the dialog inside my rounded background. And I don't want to switch to a Material theme because that changes the functionality of date and time pickers.

Instead, I had to hide the backgrounds of several subviews of the dialog in order to see the rounded background. And after doing all that, it was easier just to add the rounded background in code, too. So here's a fully programmatic (no XML) solution. This is in the `onStart` method of my `DialogFragment` subclass:

```
// add rounded corners
val backgroundShape = GradientDrawable()
backgroundShape.cornerRadius = 10.0f
backgroundShape.setColor(Color.BLUE)
this.dialog.window?.decorView?.background = backgroundShape

// make the backgrounds of the dialog elements transparent so we can see the rounded corner background
val topPanelId = this.context.resources.getIdentifier("topPanel", "id", "android")
val topPanel = this.dialog.findViewById<View>(topPanelId)
topPanel?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
val contentPanelId = this.context.resources.getIdentifier("contentPanel", "id", "android")
val contentPanel = this.dialog.findViewById<View>(contentPanelId)
contentPanel?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
val customPanelId = this.context.resources.getIdentifier("customPanel", "id", "android")
val customPanel = this.dialog.findViewById<View>(customPanelId)
customPanel?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
val buttonPanelId = this.context.resources.getIdentifier("buttonPanel", "id", "android")
val buttonPanel = this.dialog.findViewById<View>(buttonPanelId)
buttonPanel?.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
```