# Dialog with rounded corner in android

Tags: android, android-theme, android-dialogfragment

> I have gone through some solutions but none solve my issue.

I have created a custom `DialogFragment`. and root element of `dialog is cardView`. I set `cardCornerRadius` of `cardView`.

Then i try to set Transparent Dialog because background color is also showing with it.

then i try to set the dialog theme like

```
<style name="PauseDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
       <!-- TTheme.AppCompat.Translucent-->
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/PauseDialogAnimation</item>
        <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@android:color/transparent</item>


        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

The background still remains there. And then I also tried

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

but still dialog have background associated with it.

> Is there any work around. How could i get rid of it.

I have created a **DialogFragment** and in `onCreateDialog`

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(),
                R.style.PauseDialog);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.PauseDialog);
```

[image]

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but just to get sure: When do you set backgroundDrawable of Your dialog? It´s important to set it BEFORE setContentView() and show()....

Comment: try adding shape with rounded corners as background

Comment: Already tried this Vivek Mishra http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937106/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Comment: please check for edit of my answer. A tutorial is provided, you can follow that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom dialog with rounded corners in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937106/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want rounded corner you can try apply custom shape using xml to your custom dialog backgroud. Following code will help you out.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        <corners
            android:radius="10dp"/>

    </shape>
```

You can remove cardview as top element because dialog has its on shadow and depth.
Add this line before you set contentview to dialog

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use in parent style a no title bar theme and make it translucent:

```
<style name="PauseDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
  ....rest of your style
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>      
 <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: showing black background and animation also not showing

Comment: are u using "dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.PauseDialog)" and "dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));"?

Comment: rcorbelini I have updated the question. and yes I m calling AlertDialog like this

Answer (score 0):

I arrived late but with the solution to your question. just use the `android:dialogCornerRadius` in your style file.

Use it like this in your values/styles:

```
<item name="android:dialogCornerRadius">20dp</item>
```

Comment: Available only from API level 28 onwards ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set corner radius of your whole app then you can paste this line in values/themes/themes.xml. It will set corner radius on your whole app dialogs.

```
<item name="dialogCornerRadius">10dp</item>
```

Comment: Available only from API level 28 onwards ...