# Custom alert dialog with rounded corners and a transparent background

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components, material-components-android

How can I design a custom alert dialog with rounded corners and a transparent dismiss button?

Comment: I need only rounded corner and transparent dismiss button,not the whole view.

Comment: asking question need to show minimum effort

Comment: @Rasel Can you help me out with this?

Comment: First Google it..you can find. Don't post your question directly.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937106/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement a custom AlertDialog View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view)

Answer (score 34):

Create your dialog like this:

```java
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                                            context, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

In your *styles.xml* file:

```xml
<style name="CustomAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/popup_background</item>
</style>
```

In file *popup_background.xml*, write whatever corner radius you want:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>
```

You can change the corner radius.

Comment: if I want to use gradient, how will I accomplish it sir?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android 
The answer to this question should help you, change the popup_background into a gradient shape.

Comment: This one pretty good solution but one issue I face dialog width changed as compare to original alert dialog. you have any solution for same.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [Material components for Android library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) and the [`androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AlertDialog.html).

Just use something like:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Dialog")
            .setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor ....")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", /* listener = */ null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", /* listener = */ null)
            .show();
```

Using a [Material Components Theme](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#material-components-themes) you can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#customizing-component-shapes) of your component with the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute in your style.

Something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
  </style>
```

Here you can define the rounded corners:

```
  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Comment: Works! The best alternative I could find. Setting another drawable modifies the size of the dialog box, so it is not an option

Comment: What a great answer, this suppose to be the correct answer, I agree with @NicolásVera

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It worked for me like a charm.

I am working on sdkversion 28 with a minimum SDK version 19.

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: OP asked for rounded corners *and* transparent background. Do you have any suggestion for the corners?

Comment: nice :X its working for alertDialog

Answer (score 0):

You *can* create your customview by extending the alert dialog class.

But I would recommend a [PopupWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html) or a subview that you show with an animation when a specific action performed.

Or you can make an activity with a transparent background by adding this attribute to your *Manifest.xml* file:

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try it...

```
 final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

 // Include the dialog.xml file
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_custom_layout);

 // Set the dialog title
 //dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

 // Set values for custom dialog components - 
 // text, image and button
 final EditText name = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.name_edit);

 dialog.show();

 /
 Button editButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editbtn);

 // If the decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
 editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Close dialog

         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 });

 final Button cancenbtn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancelbtn);

 // If the decline button is clicked, close the custom dialog
 cancelnbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // Close dialog

         dialog.dismiss();
     }
 });
```