# Add rounded corner to Alert Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog, material-components-android

I'm trying to add rounded corners to `AlertDialog`, but I don't understand the logic of the shape file (which doesn't work). I'm using it as background in the `RelativeLayout` of the `AlertDialog`, but it seems that it gets ignored. This is the shape file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

This is the alert dialog xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".UserList"
    android:background="@drawable/shape_dialog">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_titile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scegli un'operazione"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="#D3D3D3"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vuoi aprire o eliminare il test?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_titile" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_neutral_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Indietro"
        android:layout_below="@id/dialog_tv"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_3" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_positive_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Apri"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/dialog_neutral_btn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_3"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_negative_btn"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:text="Elimina"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/dialog_positive_btn"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/dialog_neutral_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_3"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[And this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snw9h.jpg)
What did I miss?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make custom dialog with rounded corners in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937106/how-to-make-custom-dialog-with-rounded-corners-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your shape and it looks good on my phone, I have this shape that works the same way + have gradiant :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:angle="-90"
    android:centerColor="#F2F2F2"
    android:endColor="#ADA996"
    android:startColor="#DBDBDB" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#000000" />
<corners android:radius="8dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" />
</shape>
```

- Try to use the shape above, If it will not work anyway try to use your shape on a single button - if you will see your shape working correctly you will know that your problem is coming from your layout file.
- And maybe all you need to do `Invalidate Caches/Restart`, it is possible that you have no mistakes but your app is using old shape coming from the cache

Comment: I think AlertDialogBuilder behaviour is varies with Different versions . Thats what i think and If invalidating studio helps thats Perfect anyways havent tried that ever

Answer (score 3):

Just use the official [Material AlertDialog](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) included in the official Material Components for Android library.

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(context)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage("Message")
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", null)
            .show();
```

and use the theme

```
<item name="materialAlertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog</item>
```

It follows the guidelines:

[image]

You can [customize the shape](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md#customizing-component-shapes) of your component using the **`shapeAppearanceOverlay`** attribute.

Something like:

```
  <!-- Alert Dialog -->
  <style name="MyThemeOverlayAlertDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialAlertDialog">
    <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded</item>
  </style>

  <style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.MyApp.Dialog.Rounded" parent="">
    <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
    <item name="cornerSize">8dp</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea if it is possible to customize the corner radius using `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul You can define a style (that you can pass to `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`) using the `shapeAppearanceOverlay` attribute. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Your shape_dialog.xml should be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <solid
     android:color="@color/white"/>
   <corners
      android:radius="30dp" />
   <padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

You need to set the background of the dialog's transparent like.

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Dialog` Class instead of `AlertDialogBuilder`.

**Code Snippet**

define this method `showDialog()` with using Dialog class instead of `AlertBuilder`

```
public void showDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);

    Button dialog_neutral_btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_neutral_btn);
    Button dialog_positive_btn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_positive_btn);
    Button dialog_negative_btn=dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_negative_btn);
    TextView dialog_titile = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_titile);
    TextView dialog_tv = dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_tv);


   // do you stuff here , define click listeners

    dialog.show();
}
```

**Usage**

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           showDialog();
        }
    });
```

Note:-

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog
```

instead of

```
android.app.AlertDialog
```

> **Incase you want to go with AlertDialogBuilder**

Comment: I don't think that your answer is very relevant, he is asking here how to make round corners and not how to show a dialog. You are welcome to correct me if I am wrong

Comment: And like i mentioned use Dialog class "Instead" of AlertDilogBuilder" is the solution that i have answered for the problem

Comment: In that case, it was my misunderstanding. You got my upvote

Comment: Your upvote matters to me only if my answer is working .. Here to help with answers which works for them though .. I am not the best but i am learning :)

Comment: I have faced issues with AlertDialogBuilder behaviour on Different Versions so i go for Dialog class

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by doing below steps.

You have to create two shape drawable xml for Textview and for main layout

```
1. border_no_white_bg.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/white" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/white" />

  <corners android:radius="6dp" />
</shape>



2. shape_button_orange_bg_with_radius.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="@color/black" />
  <corners android:radius="15dp" />
</shape>

3. Now in main_popup.xml, replace by below code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_no_white_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="#CCCCCC"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Scegli un'operazione"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Vuoi aprire o eliminare il test?"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_button_orange_bg_with_radius"
            android:text="Indietro"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_button_orange_bg_with_radius"
                android:text="Apri"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_button_orange_bg_with_radius"
                android:text="Elimina"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>


     </LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>


4. popup_window_animation
   Inside res->values->style.xml, add this code



<style name="popup_window_animation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

Now Create a method to invoke this layout

```
public void showPopup(View anchorView) {

    final View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_popup, null);

    RelativeLayout layout_close;
    // Declare your views here

    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.style.popup_window_animation);

    layout_feedback_close = (RelativeLayout) popupView.findViewById(R.id.layout_feedback_close);
    // Here find view by ids

    layout_feedback_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
    int location[] = new int[2];
    anchorView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(anchorView, Gravity.CENTER, location[0], location[1] + anchorView.getHeight());
     }
```