# how to create a floating window like truecaller in android

Tags: java, android

[image]

this is an image that I've taken from the popup window of Truecaller
I'm working on an android app in which I want the exact same implementation
I've created a broadcast receiver from where I'll receive a response which will help me to know  which type of a call it is but I don't know that how can I create that floating dialog like Truecaller from onResonse() pls guide me through

Comment: It's looks like the MaterialAlertDialog with custom view inside there is an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62432311/7085389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using dialog fragment in your app and implements as you like

```
 Class myfragment extends dialogFragment{
    // do your stuff here 
  }
```

Comment: Nope this only works when the app is open.